# Azure App Service configuration settings (environment variable) does not work

Tags: azure, environment-variables, azure-web-app-service, app-service-environment

I created an environment variable in Azure App Service. However, I'm not able to pick the value from Azure while it is published.

So I added it to the appsettings.json, and it works.

My question would be, if I add an environment variable in Azure configuration settings, shall I add it in the appsettings.json as well, or is having it in the Azure environment settings enough?

[image]

When I navigate to

```
https://your-web-name.scm.azurewebsites.net/Env.cshtml
```

I can clearly see the variable is present there. Why is this not being picked up in the code? Am I doing something wrong?

```
appSettings["MailKitPassword"] <-- This is not being picked up, so I have to hard-code it.
```

Comment: have you tried using Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("APPSETTING_MailKitPassword") or Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("MailKitPassword")?

Comment: I was using this var appSettings = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings;  I will try using your one and come with updates

Comment: @ThiagoCustodio Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("APPSETTING_MailKitPassword") worked! thanks.

Comment: I've put as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to retrieve it you should use Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("APPSETTING_MailKitPassword")

Answer (score 2):

As Thiago Mentioned, you need to use [`GetEnvironmentVariable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.getenvironmentvariable?view=netframework-4.8) method to retrieve the AppSettings values,

[image]

so your code should be

```
Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("APPSETTING_MailKitPassword")
```

However i would recommend you to store the passwords in Azure **[KeyVault](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/key-vault/)**.

Comment: Thanks @Sajeetharan, It makes more sense now.